# How to wait for a Navigation.PushAsync() task to complete before continue executing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have the following code:

```
 Task task = Navigation.PushAsync(myPage);
 foreach(var temp in myModel)
 {

      //do bla bla
 }
```

On the page I called, when I am done executing what I need, I do this:

```
this.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

The problem is I would like to execute my `for` loop only after my `task` has completed executing or after my `myPage` has completed executing.

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Do you want the page to execute specific tasks before the loop starts or is it enough for it to be appeared? You could subscribe to the "Appearing" event of myPage and on its invocation you execute your for-loop. If your page has to do specific tasks, you could create an event on the page which will be invoked as soon as these tasks are finished and consume it the same way you would consume the "Appearing" event

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are in an async method, you can change your implementation to

`await Navigation.PushAsync(myPage)`

then continue with your for loop.

If you are not in an async method, you can call the method and force a blocking wait by calling GetAwaiter().GetResult();

```
Navigation.PushAsync(myPage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: The for loop is still executing before the task completes. I guess the await Navigation.PushAsync(myPage) just called or open my page, but it does not wait for that task to complete before continuing the execution on the current page.

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want that the foreach loop is executed after `this.Navigation.PopAsync()` has been executed. Right?

I would propose one of the following approaches:

1) Do the task on (pushed) `myPage`'s when it get's it `PopAsync()`: You could hand over whatever data (e.g. `myModel`) you need in an object to `myPage` and execute the loop in

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    foreach(var temp in myModel)
    {
         //do bla bla
    }
}
```

2) You set a flag on your original page that it has been hidden by the `pushAsync(myPage)` and deal execute your code after reappearing.

```
bool pushStarted;

protected void YourMethod()
{
    pushStarted = true;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(myPage);
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if(pushStarted)
    {
        pushStarted = false;
        foreach(var temp in myModel)
        {
             //do bla bla
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling an event from the page's OnDisapearing method, this event can then be subscribed by the navigation service which you create, and you can then use the `"TaskCompletionSource"` to wati until your page finishes its work and then complete the task. 
For more details about accomplishing this, [you can check this blog post.](https://doumer.me/xamarin-forms-tips-navigate-to-a-page-and-wait-results/)

Here is an overview of the navigation service you should use:

```
public async Task<T> NavigateToModal<T>(string modalName)
    {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        if (modalName == nameof(NewItemPage))
        {
            var page = new NewItemPage();
            page.PageDisapearing += (result) =>
            {
                var res = (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
                source.SetResult(res);
            };
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page));
        }
        return await source.Task;
    }
```